# webpack and CleanWebpackPlugin seem to delete output.path on start and every save instead of initial time only

Tags: webpack

After updating to webpack 3.10.0 and clean-webpack-plugin to 2.0.1 then updating webpack.js config to use `cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns`. Output.path get cleaned up on every save instead of only once during initial run.

webpack.js

```
output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp', 'public')
  },
...
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/[name].bundle.css'),

    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp')],
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    }),
```

I wonder, it doesnt like path.resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I have reached out to the extension author, and the simple fix was to add folders to .tmp dir to ignore.

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp')],
      cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['!images/**/*', '!fonts/**/*'],
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
```

,